# Replacing bathroom switch from single to double switch

Tags: bathroom

I tried to replace my bathroom switch so the light and the fan would run on a seperate switch.  One of the wires has 3 wires.  What do I do with the red one?

Comment: Can we get pictures of the wires in the ceiling box and the switch box?

Answer (score 1):

You'll connect one end of the red wire to a switch, and the other end to the fan.

Comment: Probably right (75%), but the question is vague and we really have no idea how the wiring is connected at the fan/light end. Worth a request for clarification and maybe a picture of the ceiling box?

Comment: @bib Vague questions get vague answers. They can't all be winners.